# Change a Content Section's name in the URL

Tags: hugo

I have a content section called `foo`, with several pages whose path is `content/foo/pageNNN.md`. They are rendered at `/foo/pageNNN/index.html`.

What if I wanted my `foo`s to become `bar`s? Do I have to rename the folder, or is there a way to just change the destination URL to `/bar/pageNNN/index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in your config file:

```
permalinks:
  foo: /bar/:filename
```

Source: https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#permalinks-configuration-example

Comment: url: would be the way I would do this, as it doesn't seem the op is trying to deal with a theme level issue, but more "site" level. https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#set-url-in-front-matter

Comment: @Rogelio Do you propose to set the adjusted url in the front matter of each page? It would work... but it is not really elegant. The OP is talking about foos and bars... not just one page.

Comment: I could see why you would say that and I agree, but, It depends I would believe. 
If it was a foundational content silo and I want a non developer or SEO marketing person to be able to address and tweak - I wouldn't put it theme level (i.e. the config). I would honestly work to lock-down things such as the config file. Now, if it's a permanent level change meaning 100's of files, or blogs, etc. etc. Then, just change the name of the content folder (i.e. folder foo, to bar), if it's just a few files that need a temp change, then I would do it per page, etc. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: @Rogelio Thank you for your elaborate answer! I fully agree.

Comment: No problem, you absolutely answered his question, but wanted to put that note and reference the docs if possible. Tks.